# Pod in pending state due to Insufficient CPU

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

On my GCE Kubernetes cluster I can no longer create pods.

```
Warning FailedScheduling    pod (www.caveconditions.com-f1be467e31c7b00bc983fbe5efdbb8eb-438ef) failed to fit in any node
fit failure on node (gke-prod-cluster-default-pool-b39c7f0c-c0ug): Insufficient CPU
```

Looking at the allocated stats of that node

```
Non-terminated Pods:        (8 in total)
  Namespace         Name                                        CPU Requests    CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ---------         ----                                        ------------    ----------  --------------- -------------
  default           dev.caveconditions.com-n80z8                            100m (10%)  0 (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  default           lamp-cnmrc                                  100m (10%)  0 (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  default           mongo-2-h59ly                                   200m (20%)  0 (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  default           www.caveconditions.com-tl7pa                            100m (10%)  0 (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  kube-system           fluentd-cloud-logging-gke-prod-cluster-default-pool-b39c7f0c-c0ug       100m (10%)  0 (0%)      200Mi (5%)  200Mi (5%)
  kube-system           kube-dns-v17-qp5la                              110m (11%)  110m (11%)  120Mi (3%)  220Mi (5%)
  kube-system           kube-proxy-gke-prod-cluster-default-pool-b39c7f0c-c0ug              100m (10%)  0 (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  kube-system           kubernetes-dashboard-v1.1.0-orphh                       100m (10%)  100m (10%)  50Mi (1%)   50Mi (1%)
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100%, i.e., overcommitted. More info: http://releases.k8s.io/HEAD/docs/user-guide/compute-resources.md)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ------------  ----------  --------------- -------------
  910m (91%)    210m (21%)  370Mi (9%)  470Mi (12%)
```

Sure I have 91% allocated and can not fit another 10% into it. But is it not possible to over commit  resources?

The usage of the server is at about 10% CPU average

[image]

What changes do I need to make for my Kubernetes cluster to be able to create more pods?

Comment: Did you try enabling Autoscaling in Kubernetes?  http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/07/autoscaling-in-kubernetes.html

Comment: yes. I have added autoscaling. But it can not grow pods due to ressource limitations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the overcommit is currently not supported. It's in planned improvements http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources.
Related issue on github: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/168

ps: in theory you can define custom node capacity, but I not sure.

Comment: Hi. That is a shame. It it makes it difficult for rolling updates because they don't work due to CPU constraints although it is only using 10% of the CPU... any ideas how to work around this?

Answer (score 44):

I recently had this same issue. After some research, I found that GKE has a default `LimitRange` with CPU requests limit set to `100m`.

You can validate this by running `kubectl get limitrange -o=yaml`.
It's going to display something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: LimitRange
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"LimitRange","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"limits","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"limits":[{"defaultRequest":{"cpu":"100m"},"type":"Container"}]}}
    creationTimestamp: 2017-11-16T12:15:40Z
    name: limits
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "18741722"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/limitranges/limits
    uid: dcb25a24-cac7-11e7-a3d5-42010a8001b6
  spec:
    limits:
    - defaultRequest:
        cpu: 100m
      type: Container
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

This limit is applied to every container. So, for instance, if you have a 4 cores node and each pod creates 2 containers, it will allow only for around ~20 pods to be created (4 cpus = 4000m -> / 100m = 40 -> / 2 = 20).

The "fix" here is to change the default `LimitRange` to one that better fits your use-case and then remove old pods allowing them to be recreated with the updated values. Another (and probably better) option is to directly set the CPU limits on each deployment/pod definition you have.

Some reading material:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#specify-a-cpu-request-and-a-cpu-limit

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-default-namespace/#create-a-limitrange-and-a-pod

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits

Comment: Dude great resource — really helped me out.  Thanks for putting it together!

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue when attempting to deploy to the cluster. In my case, there were unneeded pods being automatically created for test branches of my application. To diagnose the issue, I needed to do:

`kubectl get po`

`kubectl describe po` - for one of the existing pods, to check which node it's running on

`kubectl get nodes`

`kubectl describe node` - to see the CPU usage for the node being used by the existing pod, as below:

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                       Requests      Limits
  --------                       --------      ------
  cpu                            1010m (93%)   4 (210%)
```

Then, the unneeded pods could be deleted using:

`kubectl get deployments`

`kubectl delete deployment ....` - then name of the deployment for the pod I needed to delete.

Once I deleted enough unused pods, I was ably to deploy new ones.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR if you do use Limits and Requests:** Lower the CPU requests and/or limits.

### Context:

I was managing CPU and Memory pretty close to the limits in my case and here's what I found after some time.

Suppose that I have the following:

- A node named `node-1`, with **CPU/A = 2000 millicpu** and **MEM/A = 7827 bytes**
- An app named `app-1` I want to deploy with Helm that takes all that's theoretically available.

See screenshot below, names are slightly censored for reasons but you see the big picture.

In my case, I configure `app-1` with some `resources.limits.cpu`, `resources.limits.memory`, `resources.requests.cpu`, `resources.requests.memory` with `resources.limits.cpu` initially set to `1000m`.

### What exactly happens:

So `node-1` not only runs `app-1`, but also 3 other extra apps for other things. From top to bottom, the sum of CPU requests is `100m + 0 + 250m + 1 (1000m) = 1350m` (find it also in the allocation resources below).

All good right? Looks like it, but what if I want to deploy another version of `app-1`? In that case I would have to drop the old one and re-create it.

That might be acceptable in some cases, but when I want to deploy an update to `app-1` with Helm in my case (helm update will delete the old Pod and start a new one mind you) **without taking the old one down first** then I would get the *Insufficient CPU error*.

That's because the kube-scheduler "might" be doing the following. It takes whatever previous value you have for CPU and add its to whatever limit the new `app-1` you want to deploy has. Making the CPU requests theoretically go "beyond the requested limit". In other words it's doing an `1350 m + 1 (1000m) = 2350m` for a very short time before the other Pod is brought down. Now this is the problem since that's beyond the initial limit of `2000m`.

## Solution:

The solution in this case is to set the CPU Request to a lower number, maybe only `500m` so that the initial value is `100m + 0 + 250m + 500m = 850m`, when it does the addition then it's only `100m + 0 + 250m + 500m + 500m = 1350m` which is still below the hard limit of `2000m`. Now in my case, helm will delete the old Pod bringing the whole Request CPU usage back to `850m` but there is a very short span where it sums up the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, creating all the deployments and services in a different namespace (other than `default`) fixed this issue.